# Reading ros bag file in Ubuntu and Windows using the same code yields different formats

Tags: python, rosbag

I am currently trying to read out data from a ros bag using the python bagpy library. I have written the code for that in Windows but have recently switched to Ubuntu. If I now try to run the same code in Ubuntu the output has a different format. This is the code I used to read the data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import bagpy 
from bagpy import bagreader

class import_DVS:

    def __init__(self, dir): 
        #Directory of event data 
        self.dir = dir
        
        
    def read_data(self):
        
        #Reading data
        b = bagreader(self.dir)
        
        #Selecting relevant entries
        newmsg = b.message_by_topic(topic = 'raw_data')
        
            
        return newmsg


dir_event = 'path'
DVS_data = import_DVS(dir_event)
newmsg = DVS_data.read_data()
```

When I run this code in Windows, the varibale ´newmsg´ is a list containing all the bag data. This is the first entry of that list:

```
newmsg[0]


header:
  seq:10
  stamp:
     secs: 1455208733
     nscecs: 468284623
  frame:_id: ´´
height: 180 
width: 240 
events: 
 -
     x: 90 
     y: 47 
     ts: 
       secs: 1455208733
       nsecs: 468284623
     polarity: False 
-
     x: 82
     y: 135
     ts: 
       secs: 1455208733
       nsecs: 468330623
     polarity: False 
-
     x: 73
     y: 150
     ts: 
       secs: 1455208733
       nsecs: 468333623
     polarity: False 
-
....
```

The list contains another list (events) which has a bunch of data for each entry which I can all access individually. Using `newmsg[0].events[0].x`
e.g. lets me access the x in the first element of the events list.

However, when I run the same code in Ubuntu, a csv file is returned:

```
newmsg 


'//home/yvonne/Documents/uni_stuff/thesis/code/DVS_data/08_17/DVS-IMU-RADAR/trial1/DVS_BAG/aw_data.csv'
```

I tried accessing the elements in the events list by reading the resulting csv file with pandas like this:

```
newmsg = pd.read_csv(newmsg)
newmsg.events[0]

'[x: 167\ny: 86\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27729000\npolarity: False, x: 127\ny: 112\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27729000\npolarity: False, x: 128\ny: 5\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27730000\npolarity: False, x: 205\ny: 39\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27730000\npolarity: False, x: 233\ny: 179\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27731000\npolarity: False, x: 89\ny: 91\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27731000\npolarity: False, x: 213\ny: 28\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27733000\npolarity: False, x: 83\ny: 8\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27734000\npolarity: False, x: 226\ny: 9\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27734000\npolarity: False, x: 143\ny: 121\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27735000\npolarity: False, x: 183\ny: 176\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27735000\npolarity: False, x: 207\ny: 132\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27736000\npolarity: False, x: 48\ny: 32\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27736000\npolarity: False, x: 193\ny: 69\nts: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs:  27739000\npolarity: False, x: 229\ny: 60\nts: \n......
```

This returns one string with all the event data such that I am no longer able to access the individual entries. I am quite lost with regards to what could cause this difference, so if anyone has an idea why this happens or how I can still access the individual elements of the events list without having to loop through the massive string, I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for the version of bagpy in Windows, and Ubuntu?

You check for version by typing `pip list` and check for what version of
`bagpy` is installed in your Windows and Ubuntu.

According to the current documentation:
https://jmscslgroup.github.io/bagpy/bagpy_example.html

Calling `message_by_topic` returns a file name for decoded messages in CSV format.
Hence, add these two lines of code following your code-snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(newmsg)
```